# Forcing the router to pause until current user is loaded

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I'm using Ember Simple auth, and I'm using an initializer to set the current authenticated user as a property on my session:

```
Session.reopen({
  setCurrentUser: function() {
    var id = this.get("user_id");
    var self = this;

    if (!Ember.isEmpty(id)) {
      return container.lookup("store:main").find("user", id).then(function(user) {
        self.set("currentUser", user);
      });
    }
  }.observes("user_id")
});
```

Is it possible to force the router to wait until `currentUser` has been set before ending the initial app transition? I want certain components to be able to access `session.currentUser` as soon as the app boots up.

Answer (score 0):

I had solved a similar problem, and I concluded to set 'user' field for 'AuthController' (Session-like object) as a promise. Then, in all places where it needs I call that field and wait until the promise is fulfilled. Like this:

```
App.SomeRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    beforeModel: function(transition) {
        var auth = this.controllerFor('auth');

        if (!auth.get('isLogged')) {
            transition.abort();
            auth.set('abortedTransition', transition);

            auth.get('user')
                .then(function() {
                    transition.retry();

                    auth.set('abortedTransition', null);
                })
                .fail(function() {
                // transit to index or something like that
                });
        }

        return true;
      }
})
```

Basically, it turns down current transition, if user isn't logged into our system, and retries this transition right after user becomes authenticated.

I'm sure you can adapt this approach to your situation.